# UITableviewCell appearance animation like card flip in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have done some `UITableviewCell` appearance animation like appear from **left/right/top/bottom**.

But now there is a new requirement in my on-going project to display a `UITableViewCell` like a card flip. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had used in one of my project as below. Hope this will also help you.

To Flip the cell

```
UIView.transition(with: contentView, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.contentView.insertSubview(flipView, aboveSubview: normalView)
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
})
```

Comment: How to use this set of code in case of `UITableviewCell` ?

Comment: You can put in Button action or as per you requirement.

Comment: what are the **flipview**  **normalview**  **contentview** here ?

Comment: You have to put 2 view flipView and normalView in ContentView. When you flip it will display normalView. and when you flip flipView it display normalView